# In controller part ASP.NET MVC 4 Survey project

Tags: asp.net, admin

In the code below I have a problem:

```
    List<SurveyContext> surveys = (from s in DbContext.Surveys
                                   where s.userName == s.userName 
                                   select s.ID).ToList();
    if(surveys.Count() > 0)
                {
                   int id = 0;
                   int.TryParse(Surveys.First(), id);
                   return id;
                 }
                 return 0;
```

Error : ToList()

Error   1   A local variable named 's' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 's', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

and here:
int.TryParse(Surveys.First(), id);
The name 'Surveys' does not exist in the current context
But this name exist in context... Can anyone help me??

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1**

Use `==` instead of `=`

```
where s.userName == userName
```

**Error 2**

Try naming `s` variable on your linq query in a different way, maybe `su` or `survey`. But it seems to me that error is on code that you're not showing.

```
List<SurveyContext> surveys = (from su in DbContext.Surveys
                               where su.userName == su.userName 
                               select su.ID).ToList();
```

**Error 3**

I think you meant `surveys` instead of `Surveys` and you need to use `out` when passing `id`param

```
int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out id);
```

And since you're not evaluating parse result I'd say you should use `int.Parse`

```
id = int.Parse(surveys.First());
```

And you have to use a property of survey, you're trying to convert the entire survey instance to int

```
id = int.Parse(surveys.First().Property);
```

Comment: I did this but it gives problem in ".ToList()"

Comment: Hey @radiolaDollani, please update your question to show the new error message and/or just create a new question.  Claudio Redi has already solved 3 errors.  It takes some time, but you may need to post a new question for each problem.

Comment: @Michael La Voie: agreed :)

Comment: @radiola Dollani: I did some updates, in any case you should tell us what error you see now.

Comment: @radiola Dollani: which one?

Comment: Error 2 'MvcAnketaIT.Models.SurveyContext' does not contain a definition for 'Property' and no extension method 'Property' accepting a first argument of type 'MvcAnketaIT.Models.SurveyContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: this was the error of : id = int.Parse(surveys.First().Property);

Comment: when I did like this: int.TryParse(surveys.First(), out int id); Errors:Error 1 Invalid expression term 'int' Error 2 Invalid expression term ')' Error 3 ; expected